# Why do we disable validation rules and triggers while Data loads via loader

Tags: trigger, data-loader, validation-rule, customsetting

I'm trying to understand why do we disable validation rules and triggers while loading data via data loader or other tool. If we not disable, what will happen in the system level?

Comment: I don't think everyone does that. We do lot of data migrations,  and every time we make sure data is valid and when bringing in data to our system, we let triggers run.

Answer (score 4):

It's not mandatory. Choosing to disable validation rules, triggers, and other automation during a data load is a considered decision you make, understanding exactly what your org uses those tools to do and considering the structure of the incoming data.

Some orgs might choose to deactivate triggers to prevent bulk data from being pushed to remote systems via programmatic integration. Some might not want notifications that are done by triggers or declarative automation to go off on a bulk load. Data updates made by triggers or workflows might not be desired in loaded data. Or the data might need to be loaded in an order that isn't compatible with the way existing automation works and would cause problems.

Validation rules might need to be deactivated because they're tailored to user data input flows and would block data that's actually valid from being inserted - think about, for example, restrictions on moving Opportunities from stage to stage, that would be valid for user input but not for a bulk data load. Of course, sometimes validation rules are deactivated for less ideal reasons - to allow data to flow into the org without regard for the invariants that are expected. While this can be expedient, I've also seen it cause a lot of problems down the line.

Deactivating code and declarative automation also makes the load run a lot faster in many orgs. I've worked in orgs where inserting as few as 20 Accounts with triggers turned on caused CPU timeout errors. Deactivating the triggers (and handling their intended and desired outcomes in other ways!) can decrease load time many-fold.

In some orgs, it's fine to load data with all automation and validation turned on. In others, much more commonly, you'll want to selectively deactivate some automations and not others. Hierarchy Custom Settings can be a very useful tool for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

For two reasons: (a) for performance, and (b) to avoid disruptions while loading data. Validation rules, especially if you have a lot of them, can significantly lower performance. While it's good to have them when users are working in the system, you often prefer performance over validation when loading millions of records. Avoiding disruption while loading records is also typically important, because often, the data you're importing may not be "cleaned up", so you need those rules disabled while importing so users can deal with cleaning up the data later. Again, this is typically important to make sure that the old data can be loaded without problems.

Comment: I completely agree with this, and I understand that performance is important while loading millions of records. But, don't you think the data which is being imported is kind of mess(with all invalid/inappropriate records with missing/incorrect/no-format information)? Don't you think the end-users need to deal with all that mess in the future? And is that a good practice? Thoughts?

Comment: @ArnoldJr. Yes, the users have to deal with the fallout. But it's a tradeoff. If you keep the validation rules in place, the admin/data expert needs to deal with fixing millions (?) of records, rather than having users fix them one at a time as they come across the problem. It's often easier to have 1,000 users taking 10 minutes to fix all the problems than 1 user taking 10,000 minutes to fix all the data. Of course, this depends on the nature of the data. If the 1 user could fix them all at once, you should do so, but it's not always practical.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. As far as best practice, there isn't a hard-and-fast rule. If the users need the data *now*, albeit with some inaccuracies, disabling validation rules might be the answer. On the other hand, if the business needs *accurate data now*, then disabling validation rules might only be a performance benefit. It's up to each organization to determine their priorities. I've seen it both ways, and both were driven by business decisions, not a document produced by salesforce.

Comment: I see. My project was in the same boat, last December. We have deployed 160k Contacts by turning-off triggers, validation rules and other automation configs.  Now as our users cannot deal with that mess, we are on a way to get some Visualforce page solution using SOSL that will sit on the Contact detail page. This would help them identify some duplicate contacts based on the criteria they are looking for. And yes, it all depends on how the end-user prefers to get the data.